# Max Value of Duplicates

Tags: google-bigquery, max

I'm trying to write a query in Big Query to extract max value considering duplicate value in another column.

w        B
121     7/14
123     7/18
121     8/20
123     8/25
123     8/01
so the result should be 
w        B
121     8/20 
123     8/25

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT w, MAX(b) b
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY w
```

You can check it against dummy data in your question:

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 121 w, '7/14' b UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, '7/18' UNION ALL
  SELECT 121, '8/20' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, '8/25' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, '8/01' 
)
SELECT w, MAX(b) b
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY w
-- ORDER BY w
```

with result as

```
Row     w       b    
1       121     8/20     
2       123     8/25
```

In some case  - just simple MAX() is not enough. For example if you have date in mm/dd/yyyy format - you will need first to parse that string into date type and then apply max() as it is in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 121 w, '7/14/2018' b UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, '7/18/2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 121, '8/20/2017' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, '8/25/2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, '8/01/2018' 
)
SELECT w, MAX(PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', b)) b
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY w
ORDER BY w  

Row     w       b    
1       121     2018-07-14   
2       123     2018-08-25
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, specially for mentioning date format. Its really helpful.